# "Callout" label changes plot range

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm noticing that using `Callout` seems to override the `PlotRange` option of `Plot`, increasing it a little bit. As an MWE:

```
Plot[
 x^2,
 {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 6}}
 ]
```

produces the desired plot with the desired range

[image]

but

```
Plot[
 Callout[x^2, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", {0.8, 2.0}, 1.0],
 {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 6}}
 ]
```

Increases the plot range slightly to about `{{0,2.05}, {0,6.5}}`, even though the callout label is well within the original bounds.

[image]

There is a similar question [here, "Plot extends beyond given range"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197330/plot-extends-beyond-given-range/197346#197346), but their function and solution seem much more involved than I feel should be available.

Thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: It seems like a bug.

Comment: Try adding the `PlotRangePadding -> None` option.

Comment: @creidhne thank you! I found that the plotted function was continuing to be plotted beyond the desired range, even when setting `PlotRangeClipping->True` in the original `Plot` call, but saving the over-extended plot to `plt` and re-stating it by `Show[plt, PlotRangeClipping->True]` fixed that. (This happened to be easier in my actual case than just trimming the plotting bounds, so thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: @user241891 turn your comment into a self answer! That may be interest For the next reader

Answer (score 2):

At @MarcoB's suggestion, I'm summarizing the relevant resolutions here.

@creidhne swoops in with the definitive fix to just add `PlotRangePadding -> None` to the `Plot` options. This worked beautifully for the axes, but did not restrict the domain on which the function was actually being plotted. This isn't really an issue in my MWE, but my actual problem was a `ListPlot` which had nonuniformly distributed data which I didn't want to plot beyond a particular value, so just specifying the `PlotRange` didn't fix the issue.

I found that setting `PlotRangeClipping -> True` in `Plot` did not fix this, but saving the plot ( `plt = Plot[...]` ) and then reasserting the options with `Show[plt, PlotRangeClipping->True]` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you! (+1)